# How to get the rolling sum of last 2 years of sales relative to each month in a given period in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

As the title says, I want to, for each month inside a given period, get the rolling sum of the last 24 months.

English is not my first language so I'll try to clarify:
Let's say I define a period starting on january 2020 and ending on january 2022.

For each month inside this period, I want to sum the total sales of the preceding 24 months.

For example, for january of 2020, I'll sum all sales between january **2018**(this is important, because the period starts in 2020, but I have to sum sales from the previous 2 years relative to the month I'm processing) and january 2020. For february 2020, I'll sum all sales between february 2018 and february 2020, and so on and so forth.

My sales collection looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    saleDate: ISODate("2018-01-01"),
    salesCount: 121,
  },
  {
    saleDate: ISODate("2018-01-02"),
    salesCount: 234,
  },
  {
    saleDate: ISODate("2018-01-03"),
    salesCount: 521,
  }
]
```

As a result, I want to get something like this:

```json
[
  {
    year: 2020,
    month: 1,
    lastTwoYearSales: 8198
  },
  {
    year: 2020,
    month: 2,
    lastTwoYearSales: 9928
  },
  {
    year: 2020,
    month: 3,
    lastTwoYearSales: 9218
  },
  ...
  {
    year: 2022,
    month: 1,
    lastTwoYearSales: 11219
  }
]
```

Here's what I have so far using the aggregate pipeline:

```json
[
  {
    $match: {
      saleDate: {
        $gte: ISODate("2018-01-01"),
        $lt: ISODate("2022-02-01")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: { $year: "$saleDate" },
        month: { $month: "$saleDate" }
      },
      monthlySales: { $sum: "$salesCount" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.month",
      monthly_sales: {
        $push: {
          year: "$_id.year",
          monthlySales: "$monthlySales"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      month: "$_id",
      rolling_sum: {
        $map: {
          input: "$monthly_sales",
          as: "sales",
          in: {
            year: "$$sales.year",
            monthlySales: {
              $sum: {
                $cond: [
                  { $gte: ["$$sales.year", { $subtract: ["$_id", 2] }] },
                  "$$sales.monthlySales",
                  0
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

That's as far as I could get to, but there's a couple of problems with the above query.

First off, it sums the entire previous two years. Even if I'm currently processing july of 2021, it will include sales from january to june 2019 in the sum.

It will also sum sales from the last 2 years to the end of the period, not until the current month. And I couldn't wrap my head around how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Jsre8F6ClrM)?

Comment: No, that's not it. But I'll look into $setWindowFields, seems promising.

Comment: I'm on MongoDB 4.2, $setWindowFields is not available to me.

Comment: Can you upgrade your MongoDB? Making it without $setWindowField will require a lot of code.

Comment: Sadly, I can't. I ended up just grouping the sales by year and month and doing the rest using code. I'll leave the question open, let's see if someone show up with a pure query solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below query and check if this helps with your requirements?

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      saleDate: {
        $gte: ISODate("2018-01-01"),
        $lt: ISODate("2022-02-01")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: { $year: "$saleDate" },
        month: { $month: "$saleDate" }
      },
      monthlySales: { $sum: "$salesCount" }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "_id.year": 1,
      "_id.month": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      monthly_sales: {
        $push: {
          year: "$_id.year",
          month: "$_id.month",
          monthlySales: "$monthlySales"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$monthly_sales"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$monthly_sales.month",
      sales: { $push: "$monthly_sales" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      month: "$_id",
      rolling_sum: {
        $map: {
          input: "$sales",
          as: "sale",
          in: {
            year: "$$sale.year",
            month: "$$sale.month",
            lastTwoYearSales: {
              $reduce: {
                input: {
                  $slice: [
                    "$sales",
                    { $subtract: ["$$sale.month", 24] },
                    "$$sale.month"
                  ]
                },
                initialValue: 0,
                in: { $sum: "$$this.monthlySales" }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$rolling_sum"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$rolling_sum"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: It doesn't works. I don't think it helps to subtract 24 for a given month, it will end up with negative month numbers.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/xtSzLZzkT4K